# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionMenuTextColor' with value '@color/actionbar_text')

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Unable to resolve "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionMenuTextColor' with value '@color/actionbar_text')."  Using eclipse with current SDK. Min for this tutorial app is 14 and target is 19.

Seems like it should be simple but I have not found any answer for this. The logic is in the res/values/themes.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style
    name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
  </style>
  <!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style
    name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
  </style>
  <!-- ActionBar title text -->
  <style
    name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
  </style>
  <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
  <style
    name="MyActionBarTabText"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

"@color/actionbar_text)" In this line "@color" means that it is referring to a "color.xml" file which should be in "res/velues/" to solve this problem.

You can create your "color.xml" file in following way ,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <resources>

    <color name="actionbar_text">#ffffff</color>

    </resources>
```

"#ffffff" is hex color code for white color, you may google for more codes.

here is the link for your help [Color Codes and Names](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a color defined in your /res/values/colors.xml file that is named "actionbar_text"?

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip file from [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100).  Be sure that the first field in the form is blank (if 'example' is in this field, be sure to delete it).  Extract the resulting zip file into your project's res (resources) folder.  This will plug in all of your missing style components, and you should be ready to roll  :)